# Natbib executed and no reference

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm using Texmaker and I've followed several websites saying about running latex then bibtex, then latex twice more but I get several errors trying latex and therefore use just pdflatex.

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation 'hayes:1995' on page 4 undefined on input line 144.
Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.
```

I have defined \bibliographystyle{plainnat} and \bibliography{References} in my tex file and also used \citep{hayes:1995}. The following is the section in the 'Reference.bib' file.

```
% References
@Book{hayes:1995,
  author    = "Hayes, Bruce",
  title     = "Metrical stress theory: principles and case studies",
  publisher = Chicago,
  year      = 1995,
   address   = Chicago:adr
}
```

I however do this I only my text with to the power of a question mark symbol. Help?! It just doesn't appear to work in any way I execute the files (I'm working on Windows 7 OS currently as well). Thank you in advance for anyone's help!

Comment: When you run pdflatex, and then bibtex, do you get any error in the BibTeX run?

Comment: No funnily enough. Which doesn't make sense to me.